# Как различать обстоятельства?

Tags: синтаксис

Как различать обстоятельства образа действия и обстоятельства, выраженные сравнительными оборотами?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обстоятельство образа действия отвечает на вопросы "как?", "каким образом?" и обозначают характеристику действия или способ его осуществления. То есть, речь идет о действии. 
Например: *"Сверкая, блещут звезды"*.
В случае сравнительного оборота речь идет не о характере действия, а о характере объекта или ситуации.
Например: *"Она благоухала духами, точно парфюмерная лавка"*.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Сравнительный оборот - это обстоятельство сравнения со сравнительными союзами "точно", "как", "словно", "будто".